# Cycle through xsl:key, output results, add delimiter - but skipping some results

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an `xsl:key` that I am using with a large text-based XML file, using XSL 3 processed by Saxon.

`<xsl:key name="getcommonseg" match="seg[@master-id]" use="@master-id"/>`

This key is passed against thousands of elements that look like this:

`<seg id="unique_id_here" master-id="master-id_here">`

The `@master-id` is actually one of the `@id`s that 'groups' a number of `<seg>` together. For example:

```
<seg id="1-A" master-id="1-A"/>
<seg id="1-G" master-id="1-A"/>
<seg id="2-G" master-id="2-G"/> 
<seg id="10-Y" master-id="1-A"/>
<seg id="5-C"/>
<seg id="6-B" master-id="2-G"/>
<seg id="8-R"/>
<seg id="11-K" master-id="2-G"/>
<seg id="19-D" master-id="1-A"/>
<seg id="22-T" master-id="2-G"/>
[...]
```

When I am reporting any given `<seg>`, I use the `<xsl:key>` to find the rest any related `<seg>`. For example, if I am positioned on:

```
 <seg id="11-K" master-id="2-G"/>
```

I apply the key, and then cycle through the returned records, output them separated by a comma, and reject the record that is the current record:

```
<template match="seg[@commonid]">
  <xsl:variable name="masterid" select="./@master-id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="currentid" select="./@id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="'Seg' || ./@id || 'corresponds to the following seg id(s): ' "/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('getcommonseg',$masterid)">
       <xsl:if test="./@id != $currentid">
          <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</template>
```

This outputs:

```
Seg 11-K corresponds to the following seg id(s): 2-G, 6-B, 22-T
```

As you can see it doesn't output value '11-K' and adds commas appropriately. However, if the position was:

```
<seg id="22-T" master-id="2-G"/>
```

It would output:

```
Seg 22-T corresponds to the following seg id(s): 2-G, 6-B, 11-K,
```

...adding the last comma inadvertently.

How can I avoid this problem of the final comma when the last node is skipped/rejected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2 or 3 you should simply use `<xsl:value-of select="(key('getcommonseg', @master-id) except .)/@id" separator=", "/>`, instead of "cycling".